# In Python (or Mac OS): two different files recognized as same file and gets re-written

Tags: python, macos, unix

Simplified description of problem, I have:

dir and file structure:

```
./top.py
./Task/Task.py   (was deleted and then renamed as:)
./Task/task.py
```

`top.py` import `task.py`. But then when I run `top.py`, I saw that the `task.py` automatically changed to `Task.py`.

Why is this happening?

(I use mvim as the editor on Mac OS 10.6.)

Comment: Mac OS X is _not_ a traditional UNIX. By default, many Mac OS X filesystems are created with a case insensitive (case preserving) file system. This may be affecting your issue.

Answer (score 3):

The default file system of Mac OS X is case insensitive, but case preserving, as Charles said (this file system is called Mac OS Extended, or [HFS Plus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus), and is configured by default as being case insensitive). So, in effect, ./Task/Task.py and
./Task/task.py are the *same* file (you can read Task.py with `open('task.py')`, in Python, for instance), but the name that was used upon creating the file is kept with the original case.

If you really need to distinguish between Task.py and task.py, you might want to create a case-sensitive disk image and work from it (this issue is [discussed](https://blog.breadncup.com/2010/04/16/mac-osx-hfs-is-case-insensitive-filesystem-by-default/) on the web).

Answer (score 1):

The case of file on OSX will be preserved to whatever the file was originally created with. Hence `mv Task.py task.py` won't work. If you wish to rename the file you generally need to rename it to something else first. You can do this at command line by doing:

```
cd Task
mv Task.py temp.py
mv temp.py task.py
```

P.S. If your files are under git revision control it gets even more complicated.